# jQuery не работает в WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Есть страница singl-portfolio.php на ней должна располагаться галерея которая работает при помощи такого скрипта(jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#lightgallery').lightGallery({
        pager: true
    });
});
```

Нашла, что данный знак ($) нужно заменить на (jQuery) и тогда код будет работать в WordPress, но увы, это не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие есть еще решения данной проблемы.

Comment: Какие-нибудь ошибки в консоли выводятся? (F12)

Comment: да, выводиться JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
mobisolstudio.com/:301 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).lightGallery is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (mobisolstudio.com/:301)
    at i (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js:2)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery запускается в WordPress в compatibility mode, поэтому `$` не работает. Скрипты надо оборачивать так:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#lightgallery').lightGallery({
        pager: true
    });
});
```

Обратите внимание на 1 строку - `jQuery` и `function($)`.

Кроме того, как выяснилось, вы запускаете этот скрипт прямо в php-файле. Это плохая практика. Если скрипт, в котором определена функция `lightGallery()` стартует в футере, то ваша конструкция работать не будет.

Надо пользоваться `wp_enqueue_script()` и объявлять там зависимости скриптов.

Comment: это тоже не работает, пробовала так

Comment: Я на 200% уверен, что вы невнимательно использовали совет. function должна быть от $ - у вас так?

Comment: проверила трижды

Comment: Тогда показывайте, где и как вы это используйте. У меня эта конструкция рабоатет на каждом первом сайте.

Comment: А, так у вас в комментарии написано, что не в $ проблема,  а в lightGallery - эта функция не определена на момент вызова. Порядок запуска скриптов не тот, значит.

Comment: простите это просто конкретно сейчас а так весь jqury на проекте не работае

Comment: У вас jquery.js есть, и он работает, о чем говорит строка `jquery.js:2`

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-wordpress

Comment: я вам ещё раз говорю - неправильный порядок подключения скриптов